# Select K numbers from N numbers fairly

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, algorithms, permutations, random

I want to fairly select K numbers out of an array of N number. I know that this problem can be solved using Reservoir Sampling but I want to know if this approach is correct too?

```
1. Generate a random number for every element of the array.
2. Select those numbers in the set of K numbers whose corresponding random number lie in the top(greatest) K random numbers.
```

Comment: Why don't you just shuffle the array and pick the first $k$ numbers?

Comment: I can and I know that it would work. I just want to know if the above approach is correct or not.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that approach is working. Essentially, you first produce a ranom permutaion of all numbers and then pick the first $k$. While inefficient for many scenarios, this may be a nice and simple method e.g. as a one-liner in SQL - but I'm note sure how well the performance will be even ther (for cases of $n\gg k$).

Comment: No, what you are saying is different. You are randomly permuting the N numbers using Fisher-Yates shuffle and then selecting the first K numbers which is perfectly fine. But, what I am doing is not the same.